# Must a catch be taken cleanly to win a mark?

Tags: rules, rugby-union

In the 2019 laws, a mark is referred to in Law 17:

> To claim a mark, a player must:
>
> Have at least one foot on or behind their own 22-metre line when catching the ball or when landing having caught it in the air; and
>
> Catch a ball that has reached the plane of the 22-metre line directly from an opponent’s kick before it touches the ground or another player; and
>
> Simultaneously call “mark”.

In the 2017 laws, the wording included a reference to a "**clean** catch"

> To make a mark, a player must be on or behind that player’s 22-metre line. … The player must make a clean catch direct from an opponent’s kick and at the
> same time shout “Mark”.

The laws don't appear to include a definition of mark, only some necessary conditions. (For example it doesn't say that a mark must be taken in the field of play.) But the omission of 'clean' seems to be strange. Is it an intentional omission?

Comment: Law 17 **is** the definition of mark. The law is also clear that a mark is only possible inside the field of play, either in the 22 or the in-goal that the player calling mark is defending, both by principle and by the locations that the resulting free kick is taken from.

Answer (score 1):

No. A mark does not have to be taken cleanly under the 2019 rules. The player claiming the mark does not need to be stationary either. They just need to catch the ball and call out "mark" (within their defensive 22)